# Loop to find an app from a file and pull it with adb shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm beginning with bash, I'm writing a script that read a file, search an information in an android device for each line (each line of the file is the name of an app installed on the device)

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
    name="$line"
    echo "App : - $name" | adb shell pm path $name

done < "$filename"
```

Here the result of this script

```
package:/data/app/com.naver.linewebtoon-1/base.apk
package:/data/app/com.game5mobile.lineandwater-2/base.apk
```

How can I get each result line as a parameter for an other function

```
adb shell cat /data/app/com.naver.linewebtoon-1/base.apk > app1.apk 
adb shell cat /data/app/com.game5mobile.lineandwater-2/base.apk > app2.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo "App : - $name" | adb shell pm path $name` would invoke `adb` as a command, sending echo's output to its standard input.  That won't achieve your goal of just echoing the composed command.

Use IFS to read the delimited data in your file and print out the composed command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
count=0
while IFS=: read -r _ path  # ignore the first field by reading it into a dummy variable
do
    printf '%s\n' "adb shell cat $path > app$((++count)).apk"
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line number to each line of your file and then read `:` separated fields from file like this:

```
nl -w1 -s: "$filename" |
while IFS=: read -r cnt _ name; do
    echo "adb shell cat \"$path\" > \"app$cnt.apk\""
done
```

If your learning, for sure check [man nl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nl) and [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)? from greg's wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).